# Network issue. Ifup says unknown interface

Tags: ubuntu, networking, interface

This is the output of ifconfig

```
# ifconfig
enp0s3    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 08:00:27:ef:b6:e6
          inet addr:192.168.2.3  Bcast:192.168.2.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::cf19:776a:4d5c:36e0/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:713069 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:6767 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:45869812 (45.8 MB)  TX bytes:667164 (667.1 KB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:1108 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:1108 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:86846 (86.8 KB)  TX bytes:86846 (86.8 KB)
```

When I do

```
# ifdown enp0s3
```

It says **Unknown interface enp0s3**

The network is fine and works without any issues.
Its just the command that does not work

Ubuntu 16.04 (Xenial)

Below is the output of `ip a s`

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
inet6 ::1/128 scope host
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp0s3: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 08:00:27:ef:b6:e6 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.2.7/24 brd 192.168.2.255 scope global enp0s3
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::cf19:776a:4d5c:36e0/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

Below is my /etc/network/interfaces

```
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
```

Output of nmcli conn sh

```
Wired connection 1  42d740b1-21c3-3b7c-8b9e-5922fe8a6380  802-3-ethernet  enp0s3
```

Comment: Have you tried `ip link set dev enp0s3  up`  Does `enp0s3` match your configuration in `/etc/network/interfaces` ?

Comment: What is the output of ip a s ?

Comment: @bgtvfr : The output is too long to paste in one go. So Multi comment
`1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever`

Comment: @bgtvfr: Part 2 of output
`2: enp0s3: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 08:00:27:ef:b6:e6 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.2.7/24 brd 192.168.2.255 scope global enp0s3
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::cf19:776a:4d5c:36e0/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever`

Comment: @val0x00ff: Weirdly my interfaces file has only this in it
`# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
`

Comment: @searcotjabali please update your question with these additional details. Comments read very hard! Your network is controlled by `NetworkManager` and you can use `nmcli conn sh` to see the connections. Also `ifconfig` is obsoleted by `ip` which is a command from `iproute2` tools. Use `ip` instead as I stated in my first comment

Comment: @val0x00ff: Sorry. I am kinda used to ifconfig. I updated my question with the details. Thanks :-)

Comment: @searcotjabali please see `man nmcli` how to control your interfaces. You are using `NetworkManager` which controls your interfaces. The man page has many examples that show you how to bring an interface up or down.

Answer (score 24):

`ifup` and `ifdown` are used to set up interfaces listed in `/etc/network/interfaces` . `enp0s3` isn't described in this file, so it's absolutely expected that `ifup` and ifdown don't know what to do with it. Add some lines such as

```
iface enp0s3 inet dhcp
```

And you'll see that it will work much better.

Comment: Sorry, can you explain what's done here? Are you just defining the interface enp0s3 as an internet+dhcp interface?

Comment: @Hellreaver Yes. Notice that the interface must already exist in the "ip" or "ifconfig" output. For the detailed syntax of /etc/network/interfaces please Read The Fine Manual: "man interfaces" or see http://manpages.org/etc-network-interfaces/5

Answer (score 5):

I used the following commands:

```
cat /proc/net/dev
ls /sys/class/net
ip link show
ifconfig

sudo ifconfig [interface-name] down / up
```